# Ruby mechanize - discriminate two forms with their content

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have two forms with the same action, and submit button text. Only the text inside changes

```
    <li>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="">
      <input name="returnURL" value="/cap/dashboard/home" type="hidden">
      <input name="destURL" value="" type="hidden">
      <button name="login" type="submit" class="btn-primary">
        <span aria-hidden="true">Continuer</span>
      </button>
      <h2>textA</h2>
    </form>
    </li>
    <li>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="">
      <input name="returnURL" value="/cap/dashboard/home" type="hidden">
      <input name="destURL" value="" type="hidden">
      <button name="login" type="submit" class="btn-primary">
        <span aria-hidden="true">Continuer</span>
      </button>
      <h2>textB</h2>
    </form>
    </li>
```

How can I submit the right form ?

Comment: I am not super familiar with `mechanize` so I don't want to post an answer but you should be able to do something like `page.at("h2:contains('textB')").parent` to locate the "textB" form or maybe an xpath like `page.search("//ul/li/form[h2='textB']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `form_node` to search for css/xpath:

```
page.forms.find{|f| f.form_node.at('h2:contains("textB")')}
```

It wouldn't matter though, in your example both forms do the same thing.

Comment: Ah, but in my browser they don't actually do the same thing. JS in there most likely... :'(

Comment: You might want to proxy mechanize through fiddler to see what's going on there.

Comment: I ended up using Capybara with the chromedriver. Too many JS out there. But I had tried your solution on mechanize and it had worked.